# Regression by Groups

Tags: r, group-by, regression

I have a table:

```
CityData ->

City        Price     Bathrooms      Bedrooms      Porch

Milwaukee   2300      2              3             yes
Chicago     3400      3              2             yes
Springfield 2300      1              1             no
Chicago     2390      2              1             yes
```

I would like to run a regression for each city (multiple rows per city) to give me coefficients for each city.  I want to regress price on the other confounding variables (bathrooms, bedrooms, porch).

I tried the dplyr library:

```
library(dplyr)

fitted_models = CityData %>% 
    group_by(CityData$City) %>% 
    do(model = lm(CityData$Price ~ CityData$Bathrooms +
                  CityData$Porch + CityData$Bedrooms, data = CityData))
```

But the output is just

```
14    lm    list
14    lm    list
14    lm    list
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you want different intercepts for each city, or a different set of coefficients for bedrooms, bathrooms, etc. for each city? Also, to make your example reproducible, you're going to have to supply enough data to run a regression (more rows than predictors).

Comment: I want a different coefficient for the Porch variable.

Comment: Start with `lm(Price ~ City + Bathrooms + Porch + Bedrooms, CityData)`, and get more complicated as necessary from there. Also, don't use `$` subsetting in formulas or dplyr/tidy eval functions—just use the bare variable name.

Comment: I don't understand what this output is. What's 14? Are `lm` and `list` column types? If so, those are the types to be expected from that code, so you need to explain more clearly what you're getting and what you're looking for.

Answer (score 4):

You might try something like this. Here I'll use the mtcars data as an example.

```
df <- mtcars
models <- df %>% group_by(cyl) %>% summarise(mod = list(lm(mpg ~ wt)))
```

This will give you a new variable mod that holds all the info for your model. You can call the coefficients like:

```
models$mod[[1]]$coefficients
(Intercept)          wt 
39.571196     -5.647025
```

You can get more complex with it too.

```
models <- df %>% group_by(cyl) %>% summarise(mod = list(lm(mpg ~ wt + hp)))
models$mod[[1]]$coefficients
(Intercept)          wt          hp 
45.83607319 -5.11506233 -0.09052672
```

Of course `models` will also still also hold the info for the group

```
models$cyl
[1] 4 6 8
```